# Conditional form by dropdown list

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, conditional-formatting

I am making an app to attach documentation of candidates to a job position, I did it with a single form but now they asked me to add a dropdown list of the location and that, depending on the selected option, request only some of the documents on the form.

Models.py:

```
cc= (
        ('1','Quebrada Blanca'),
        ('2','Lo Pinto'),
        ('3','Oficina Central'),
        ('4','Carbonato'),
        ('5','Toconao'),
        ('6','Centinela'),
        ('7','Spence'),
        ('8','La Negra'),
    )

class Candidato(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 70, null=True, blank=True)
    rut = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key=True)
    correo = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    centro_de_costo =models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length =30, choices = cc)
    estado = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=imagen_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    File1 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File2 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File3 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File4 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File5 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File6 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File7 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File8 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File9 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
    File10 = models.FileField(upload_to=uploads, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class Candidato_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Candidato

        fields = [
            
            'File1',
            'File2',
            'File3',
            'File4',
            'File5',
            'File6',
            'File7',
            'File8',
            'File9',
            'File10',

        ]

        labels = {
            
            'File1': 'Certificado Antecedentes',
            'File2': 'Hoja de vida del conductor',
            'File3': 'Certificado de residencia',
            'File4': 'Certificado afiliación AFP',
            'File5': 'Certificado afiliacion de salud',
            'File6': 'Fotocopia de cedula de identidad',
            'File7': 'Fotocopia de licencia de conducir',
            'File8': 'Curriculum vitae',
            'File9': 'Ultimo finiquito',
            'File10': 'Documentacion que acredite el cargo',
        }

        widgets = {
            
            'File1': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File2': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File3': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File4': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File5': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File6': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File7': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File8': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File9': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'File10': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            
        }
```

Views.py:

```
class CandidatoList(ListView):
    model = Candidato
    template_name = 'candidato/candidato_list.html'
    paginate_by = 2

class CandidatoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Candidato
    form_class = Candidato_form
    template_name = 'candidato/candidato_form.html'
    success_url = 'https://www.google.cl/'



class CandidatoUpdate(UpdateView):  
    model = Candidato   
    form_class = Candidato_form
    template_name = 'candidato/candidato_form.html'
    success_url = 'http://localhost:8000/candidato/candidato_edit/17732410-8/'
```

In such a way that if the cc=1 (Quebrada Blanca) the form requests only:

File1, File3, File6, File7

And in such a way that if the cc=2 (Lo Pinto) the form requests only:

File1, File2, File7, File8.

...Etc.

Is there any way to reuse the already created form, since it contains all the requested documents, and to filter it according to the dropdown list? Or do you have to fill out several forms? And in case of requiring several, how do I define them in the view?

Template candidato_form.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    <button type="reset" onclick="return confirmarReset()">Reiniciar</button>

</form>
```